# ¿Error en código jQuery inhabilita los enlace no permite redirigir al href especifico?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un error en el código `Javascript` de `jQuery` los enlaces son inhabilitados no permite cumplir la acción.

El código `jQuery` está ocasionando que los enlaces con destino no continúen al `href` especifico.

El problema: En el siguiente código **HTML** los enlaces / vínculos `index.php, index2.php etc` no funcionan no deja cumplir la acción de seguir a la página de los respectivos enlaces.

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="dropdown3"><a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index2.php">Sub Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="index3.php">Sub Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdown4"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index4.php">Sub Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="index5.php">Sub Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

El problema esta en el código `jQuery` porque al comentar `/* */` el código, los enlaces funcionan perfectamente sin problemas.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navigation li a').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if ($('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').is (':hidden')) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
      $('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').show();
    } else {
      $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".dropdown-menu").length === 0) {
      $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los enlaces no realizan la acción de redirigir al `href` especifico es porque siempre retorna `false` el evento `click`, por lo tanto no se realiza la re dirección.
Para cambiar este comportamiento en su `else` haga un `return true` para que se ejecute la re dirección. *Tampoco hace falta aplicar el hide en el else*

```js
$(function() {
 $('.navigation li a').click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if ($('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').is (':hidden')) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
      $('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').show();
      console.log("IF");
    } else {
      $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
      return true; 
    }
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".dropdown-menu").length === 0) {
      $(".dropdown-menu").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="dropdown3"><a href="#">Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index2.php">Sub Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="index3.php">Sub Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdown4"><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="index4.php">Sub Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="index5.php">Sub Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="otraclase">
  <!-- Este enlace funciona, porque se encuentra fuera de la raíz de la ejecución del código jQuery -->
  <a href="home.php">Home</a>
</div>
```